# How to set the Access-Token for the password reset in LoopBack with the AngularJs SDK

Tags: angularjs, loopback

My Project is based on the

> Loopback Getting Started Tutorial 2

I use the AngularJs SDK on the Client-Side and I want to implement the "Password-Reset"-Function.

First there is the `/reset-password` view, where you can enter your email address and ask for another password.

Then you get a link send per email that directs you to `/set-new-password/{{accessToken}}/{{userId}}`

On this view, the user enters the password and submit it. Afterwards it should find the User by Id and update its password.

But for `User.findById` and `User.updateById` I need the access-token in the Request-Header.
"Normally" the Request-Header always contains the access-token after the login. But since it's a password-reset, I'm not logged in.

I can access the access-token via `$stateparams`, but how can I set it in the Request-Header,so I can still use the AngularJs-SDK?

(I hope everything is clear. English is not my native language)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I have found someone with nearly the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705765/reset-loopback-password-with-access-token?rq=1). The not accepted answer works for me now.

**EditEdit:** Doesn't work always.. Sometimes it doesn't change the "authorization"-parameter in the Header. Can't figure out why

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the LoopBack AngularJs SDK

In your angularJs controller

```js
.controller(function (UserAccount, $location, LoopBackAuth, $scope) {
      var params = $location.search();
      var access_token = params.access_token;
      $scope.reset = function(inputs) {
        LoopBackAuth.setUser(access_token);
        UserAccount.setPassword({ newPassword: inputs.newPassword });
      }
})
```

You need to implement error control and ideally check the password twice before sending.